# Given a semicircle, centre O. AB = 2 and BC = 2. Angle ABD is a right angle, find lengths.

Tags: geometry

[image]

The diagram shows a semicircle, centre O. AB = 2 and BC = 2. Angle ABD is a right angle.

(1) Find a simplified expression, in terms of , for the length OB.

(2) Using Pythagoras’ Theorem, or otherwise, find and simplify an expression in terms of  for $BD^2$ (the square of length BD).

(3) If the circular arc ADC has length 122, what is length BD?

Based on hints from @epsilon-emperor:

Radius (R) = x + 1

So,

1. OB = (x+1) - 2 = x - 1
2. $BD^2 = (x+1)^2 - (x-1)^2=4x, ⇒ BD = 2\sqrt{x}$
3. $2R = 2*122, ⇒ R = 122, ⇒ x=121, ⇒ BD=22$

Seems reasonable?

Comment: please show what you have tried yourself.

Comment: Sorry, updated based on hints from @epsilon-emperor

Comment: @HarryB $BD = 2\sqrt x = 22$. Rest is good.

Comment: Oops yes. Thanks @epsilon-emperor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hints:**

1. $AO + OB + BC = 2x + 2$, and $AO = OC$ since $O$ is the centre. Can you find $OB$ now?
2. From the first part, you know $OB$. $OD$ is equal to the circle's radius. Use Pythagoras Theorem on $\triangle OBD$.
3. If the radius of the circle is $R$, the length of the circular arc is half of the circle's circumference, i.e. it is $\pi R$. This gives you the radius, and hence you have $x$, using which you can find $BD$.